# Very basic indentation in Python

Tags: python

Why with these two different codes (only different by indentation) am I getting two different results?

Why is in the case of first code, the code is not executing further than 2nd item on the list?

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
        return x

print double_list(n)
// [6, 5, 7] None

n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

print double_list(n)
// [6, 10, 14] None
```

Comment: Because indentation (famously!) has syntactic meaning in Python?

Comment: Indentation is part of Python syntax. If you moved around curly brackets in C-like language, would you expect the same output to appear?

Comment: Do the instructional materials you're using really not explain how important indentation is in Python?

Answer (score 3):

Due to the indentation, in the first example, you are returning x after first iteration of the loop. In the second example, you are returning x after the loop iterates through the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is, as noted, famously important in Python. It has a similar function to braces `{}` in other languages, and indicates where certain code blocks begin and end. In your case:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
        return x
```

The `return` is *inside* the `for` loop here, and :

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x
```

*Outside* the `for` loop here.

Every time you indent your code by one more *space* (either a tab or a constant number of spaces), Python considers this nesting. That is, the first case has the `return` statement nested in the `for` loop, and so the function returns in the first iteration of the loop, whereas the second cases `return` statement is *not* nested, and thus returns as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the indentation is always relevant. Because of this, in your first code example, you are actually returning *within* the for loop. So the loop is only executing a single time and then the `return` is called, exiting the function.